# compressing with GZIPOutputStream to upload without creating a gzip file locally

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, gzipstream, gzipoutputstream

I'm trying to compress the file in java before I upload the file with `GZIPOutputStream`. Is there a way to just store the gzipped file in memory for the upload and not have it generate a gzipped file on the local computer?

Thanks!

Comment: You could store it as byte array.

Answer (score 2):

Just connect the GZipOutputStream directly to the output stream and write. No file necessary.

Comment: GzipCompressingEntity is the recommended way of doing that, as it also adjusts content-length / content-type / content-encoding request headers and ensures correct message delineation.

Comment: I was trying to look up how to use GzipCompressingEntity wasn't able to find much. Would I simply just create a entity of class GzipCompressingEntity and set that as the entity in my put request? When I do that i get a SocketTimepoutException.

Comment: Yes, you just would use GzipCompressingEntity to decorate another entity. SocketTimepoutException has nothing to do with GZIP encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Decorate content entity with `GzipCompressingEntity`

```
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("https://host/stuff");
httpPost.setEntity(new GzipCompressingEntity(new FileEntity(new File("my.stuff"))));
CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
try {
    EntityUtils.consume(response.getEntity());
} finally {
    response.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved this problem by writing to a temp file and doing a .deleteonexit on the temp file once the gzip uploading was done.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: using some stream will be the best..what if this code runs on server and never exit? or some error causing your JVM to crash?

Comment: you mean like streaming it directly to server? how does streaming handle JVM crashes? Im currently streaming to temp file using the `GZIPOutputStream` , then uploading it to the server.